# pass Json object to google charts API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'api/v1/readings',
  data: { get_param: 'readings' },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       var readings = data.readings;



       function drawChart() {
         var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
           chartdata.addColumn('datetime', 'Time of Day');
           chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Glucose Value');
           chartdata.addRows([

             readings.forEach(function(item){
               let date = new Date(item.time);
               { [[`Date(${date.getYear()}, ${date.getMonth()}, ${date.getDate()})`], item.glucose_value]}
             })
           ]);
```

So Im trying to pass a datestring from JSON `readings` to google charts api but im receiving a an error for `every row must be a null or array`.

the doc `https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#datestring` states that dates must be passed in quotes so how do i pass my `Date` variable into the the string in order to parse it into a datetime object for the chart?

Answer (score 0):

Your passing it as a object : {}

Take out the object notation and pass as [ [] ]